# Remote control Android powered TV from another Android device like google Tv remote

Tags: java, android, android-widget, google-tv

I would like to develop the remote control application for android powered TV(it's Like Google TV)
i used google tv remote app to find the android powered tv but i am unable to find the that TV's (it's finding the only GTV's)

to Search the android powered tv can i use the anymote protocol?

please help me and Thanks in Advance

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

if you want to control one device from an android device you need 2 things:

1. a physical way of communication.
2. a language to communicate in.

if you want to communicate with another device from your android device you'll probably want to use the bluetooth adapter for the device (the only problem is how to enable bluetooth pairing with the TV), or using the wifi antena (once again, not so easy to enable in a TV).

using the API's for the TV is something you should probably read about in the remote control/TV manufacturers and see how to enable that via Android.

Comment: I would like to control the android powered tv with android device via WIFI that android powered tv(Box) having the wifi